# Add rows to HTML table based on User vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp page which contains a list of more than 1000 objects. Due to my requirement I have to show all the 1000 records on the same page without any pagination.
I have a javascript method which add the rows into a table on document ready function.

I have 2 problems:
1. Javascript method has the struts tags to fetch labels and list values and then it adds rows into the HTML table. This method takes a lot of time as all the tags are taking lot of time to be resolved from server.

2. I want to add only 50 records at a time in the table and then when user scrolls vertically down, I want to somehow detect that user has reached at the end so that I can add next 50 rows in the table. As I already have all records with me I will not have to go to database to fetch next rows.

PS: All my 1000 records are from a single table and I can fetch them in no time. Problem is occurring only when rendering for those records happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, only load 50 entiries to the page on the `document.ready()` call.

Use the `.scroll()` method from jQuery to trigger the event to append 50 more entires once the user hits the end of your table.

```
 $('#table').scroll(function() {
   if($('#table').scrollTop() + $('#table').height() == $('table').height()) {
     for(var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
       //Append next value in your array to bottom
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is resolving my 2nd problem. But I am still not sure about the first one. Even if I don't call that javascript method still it takes a lot of time to render the page, but if I remove the code of that method then page gets rendered very fast.

Comment: Can you post the current code you're working with?

HTML
JS